# angularjs - webservice returns an html page instead of data

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ionic-framework, asmx

I'm using $http.get to connect to an asmx webservice passing 2 parameters: username and password. However it returns the html page of the web service instead of data. 
am I missing something?

here's my code for controller.js:

```
$scope.enterlogin = function(usern,pass)
{
      loginService.getUser(usern,pass).then(function(response){
      console.log('response is = ' + response.data);
      };
}
```

Here's my code for services.js:

```
.factory('loginService', ['$http', function($http){
var base_url = "http://<ipaddress of webservie>/UserService3/WebService1.asmx?op=getUserbyUsername";

return {
    getUser: function(usern,pass){
        console.log('code side usern is = ' + usern + "" + pass);
        return  $http.get(base_url, { params: { passw: pass, uname: usern} 
});
    }
}
}])
```

I also added these to the webservice's web.config file:

```
 <webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
</httpHandlers>
```

And this:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

and this is the webmethod in the webservice:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string getUserbyUsername(string uname, string passw)
    {
        string cs = "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = UsersDB; Integrated Security = True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetUserByUsername", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(@"Username", uname);
            SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter(@"Password", passw);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);
            User user = new User();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // user.Username = reader["Username"].ToString();
                //  user.Password = reader["Password"].ToString();
                user.IsExisting = reader["IsExisting"].ToString();
                user.UserID = reader["UserID"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();

            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change `System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory` (which is typically used for aspx endpoints) to `System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory` (which is more typically used for asmx endpoints).

EDIT: try changing the return to `void` and then doing this:

```
Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(user));
```

See if that works.

Comment: thanks. i tried changing it to .WebServiceHandlerFactory but it still returns an html page tho.

Comment: Odd: are you setting the response format of your method to JSON? Something perhaps like `[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` (hard to tell without a look at your implementation what exactly is going wrong).

Comment: i tried adding [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] to my webmethod but i get the same html page in json format.